# Why does my Keras LSTM model perform horrible compared to RandomForest on timeseries forecasting?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a DataFrame predicting the number of vehicles passing a road based on some sensor data.

The DataFrame is shaped on the following format, and is indexed based on the timestamp

```
         index           |    t   |   t - 1   |   t - 2 |  ....  |   t - 95 |  number of cars
2020-08-01 : 00:00:15        410        499         380     ...        20         240
2020-08-01 : 00:00:30        305        410         499     ...        45         244
2020-08-01 : 00:00:45        290        305         410     ...        50         188
```

The Data has the following shape `X_train.shape = (4210,97)`

What I do is the following

```
train = df.loc['2020-08-01 : 00:00:15':'2020:09:12 23:45:00']
test = df.loc['2020-09-13 : 00:00:00':]
y_train = train['number of cars']
X_train = train.drop('y',axis=1)
sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(X_train)
X_train= sc.transform(X_train)

y_test = test['number of cars']
X_test = test.drop('y',axis=1)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)


rf = RandomForest()
rf.fit(X_train,y_train)
preds = rf.predict(X_test)

print(r2_score(preds,y_test))
print(mean_squared_error(preds,y_test))
```

Which gives

```
'r2 : 0.89'
'mse : 60'
```

I wanted to see if a LSTM model could do better

```
 X_train_lstm = X_train.values.reshape(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],1)
 X_test_lstm = X_train.values.reshape(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],1)

 model = Sequential()
 model.add(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=False,activation='relu', input_shape (96, 1)))
 model.add(Dense(units=1))
 model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
 model.fit(X_train_lstm,y_train,batch_size=64,epochs=100)
 lstm_preds = model.predict(X_test_lstm)

 print(r2_score(lstm_preds,y_test))
 print(mean_squared_error(lstm_preds,y_test))
```

which gives

```
 'r2 : -0.3'
 'mse : 2100040'

  print(lstm_preds)

  [38,38.12,38.1,38,38.2,....,38]
```

The predicted values is basically the same value, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think 4210 dataset is less amount of data for deep learning model.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that your `y_train` and `y_test` are not standardized.

Also, for [LSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM) layer, you should not change the activation.